Twilio Call Forwarding Results in Application Error 12100
I’m working on a Twilio-based call automation system. The system should do the following:

Make an outbound call.

Play an audio file during the call.

Forward the call to another number if the user presses "1."


When I run this code, I hear an "Application Error" message on the call. According to Twilio's debugger, this error corresponds to Error Code 12100, which indicates a "Document parse failure". This error seems to be related to how the TwiML is being generated and returned by my server.
<?php
// Enable error reporting for debugging
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require 'vendor/autoload.php'; // Include Twilio SDK
use Twilio\Rest\Client;

// Twilio credentials
$twilioSid = ''; // Your Twilio SID
$twilioToken = ''; // Your Twilio Auth Token
$twilioFromNumber = ''; // Your Twilio phone number
$forwardNumber = ''; // Number to forward to if '1' is pressed
$audioFileUrl = ''; // URL of your audio file

// Function to start the call
function startCalling() {
    global $twilioSid, $twilioToken, $twilioFromNumber, $audioFileUrl;

    // Phone numbers to call
    $numbersToCall = ['']; // Example number

    // Create a Twilio client
    $client = new Client($twilioSid, $twilioToken);

    foreach ($numbersToCall as $toPhoneNumber) {
        try {
            // Initiate the call and listen for keypresses
            $call = $client->calls->create(
                $toPhoneNumber,  // To
                $twilioFromNumber,  // From
                [
                    'url' => '', // TwiML for call flow
                ]
            );
            echo "Call initiated to: " . $toPhoneNumber . " with SID: " . $call->sid . "<br>";
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error while calling " . $toPhoneNumber . ": " . $e->getMessage() . "<br>";
        }
    }
}

// Function to serve TwiML
function serveTwiml() {
    global $audioFileUrl;

    // Output XML response
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<Response>';
    echo '<Gather numDigits="1" action="">';
    echo '<Play>' . htmlspecialchars($audioFileUrl) . '</Play>';
    echo '</Gather>';
    echo '</Response>';
    exit;
}

// Function to handle keypresses
function handleKeyPress() {
    global $forwardNumber, $twilioSid, $twilioToken;

    $Digits = $_POST['Digits'];
    $callSid = $_POST['CallSid'];

    // Create a Twilio client
    $client = new Client($twilioSid, $twilioToken);

    if ($Digits == '1') {
        try {
            // Forward the call to the forward number
            $client->calls($callSid)->update(
                ['twiml' => '<Response><Dial>' . $forwardNumber . '</Dial></Response>']
            );
            echo "Call forwarded to " . $forwardNumber;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            echo "Error while forwarding the call: " . $e->getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        echo "No action for this digit.";
    }

    // Respond with an empty TwiML to end the gather
    header('Content-Type: text/xml');
    echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>';
    echo '<Response></Response>';
    exit;
}

// Handle POST requests
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    if (isset($_POST['action'])) {
        switch ($_POST['action']) {
            case 'start_calling':
                startCalling();
                break;
            case 'handle_key_press':
                handleKeyPress();
                break;
        }
    }
}

// Handle GET requests for serving TwiML
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET' && isset($_GET['action'])) {
    if ($_GET['action'] === 'serve_twiml') {
        serveTwiml();
    }
}

